# ng-Repeat returning undefined within $scope.$watchCollection

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, ng-init

When I console.log(result) on line 5, it returns just fine. The console.log($scope.notes) on line 11 returns undefined. Any ideas?

Here is my controller:

```
$scope.$watchCollection = (['parent_id', 'parent_type'], function(){
    $scope.loadNotes = function(){
        $http.get('/api/notes/' + $scope.parent_id + "/" + $scope.parent_type).success(function(result){
            console.log(result);
            $scope.notes = result;
            return result;
        });
    }
    $scope.notes = $scope.loadNotes();
    console.log($scope.notes);
});
```

Comment: Schw2iizer, i have posted an answer, does it clear your doubt and give an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `$http.get` is asynchronous so the line number 11 is executed before line number 5 so you get undefined there.

By **asynchronous** i mean the execution doesn't wait for $http to return the promise, it just keeps executing to next lines.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way you can return a promise so the code will wait for the asynchronous call to complete before moving forward and defining `$scope.notes`.

```
$scope.$watchCollection = (['parent_id', 'parent_type'], function(){
    $scope.loadNotes = function(){
        return $http.get('/api/notes/' + $scope.parent_id + "/" + $scope.parent_type).success(function(result){
            console.log(result);
            //$scope.notes = result;
            return result;
        });
    }
    $scope.loadNotes().then(function(loadedNotes){
        $scope.notes = loadedNotes;
        console.log($scope.notes);
    });

});
```